# Can we use "dearest" to begin an informal letter?

Tags: word-usage, writing, greetings

"***Dearest Marta, hi"*** Is it correct to begin an informal letter using "Dearest"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Since it's an informal letter, you are free to begin it however you wish.

> Dear Martha,
>    Dearest Martha,
>    Hi Martha,

All these are fine. Just remember that the salutation you choose sets the tone for the rest of the letter. [*Dearest*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dearest) is often used to refer to someone who is very close to you, like a lover or your best friend, so don't use it unless you really like Martha a lot.

Also, I wouldn't start a letter with "Dearest Martha, hi" like in your example. Your salutation is the greeting that starts your letter, and it takes the form

> [Introductory word] [Name]**,**

Since you already introduced your letter with *Dearest Martha,* there is no need to use *hi*. After your salutation, start a new line and begin the body of your letter.

Help this helps!